# Object TreeMap vs. Object HashMap in Java

Tags: java, dictionary, object, hashmap, treemap

```java
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Object, Object> m = new TreeMap();
        m.put("1", new ArrayList());
        m.put(1, new Object());
        m.put(1.0, "Hello");
        System.out.println(m);
    }
}
```

This code returns the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class java.lang.Integer (java.lang.String and java.lang.Integer are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.compareTo(Integer.java:64)
    at java.base/java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:566)
    at test.main(test.java:8)
```

but this doesn't happen with `HashMap` and compiles successfully. I want to know how is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

[`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) uses a comparator internally to build *a Red-Black tree*. In this case you didn't provide it, so it tries to compare `Integer` and `String`, that are not comparable to each other. For example, you can provide a comparator like this:

```java
Map<Object, Object> m = new TreeMap<>(Comparator.comparing(String::valueOf));
m.put("1", new ArrayList<>());
m.put(1, new Object());
m.put(1.0, "Hello");
System.out.println(m);
```

Output:

```
{1=java.lang.Object@3fee733d, 1.0=Hello}
```

First two elements are the same according to this comparator, and an element `new Object()` uses a default [`toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) method implemented.

---

[`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) uses a `hashCode` method internally to build *a Hashtable*. This method is implemented at least in the [`Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) class and is overridden by derived classes: [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode()), [`Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#hashCode()) and [`Double`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#hashCode()). That is why this code works fine:

```java
Map<Object, Object> m = new HashMap<>();
m.put("1", new ArrayList<>());
m.put(1, new Object());
m.put(1.0, "Hello");
System.out.println(m);
```

Output:

```
{1.0=Hello, 1=[], 1=java.lang.Object@5451c3a8}
```